# How to suppress "Future warning" tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, ubuntu, terminal

**I am running "./buildTF.sh" which uses TensorFlow, on ubuntu terminal. And getting the error as:**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516:
FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated;
in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670240/about-tensorflow-import, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488150/tensorflow-warning-for-data-types

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'." problem in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381430/synonym-of-type-is-deprecated-in-a-future-version-of-numpy-it-will-be-underst)

Answer (score 10):

These warnings are classical `FutureWarning`, which means you can silent them using the `warnings` module from the python standard library:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=r"Passing", category=FutureWarning)
```

This will check `FutureWarning` and silent the messages containing `r"Passing"`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with tf 1.14

Comment: Doesn't work for me with tf 1.12

Answer (score 8):

This is a warning message which comes because of numpy version, uninstall the current numpy version and update it to `1.16.4`.

```
# pip uninstall numpy 
# pip install numpy==1.16.4
```

Thanks to [ymodak](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31249)

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to tensor flow, you can use following code:
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True